# In XCode 6 is there a simple way to build an iOS universal application and 32/64 static library subprojects?

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

The common wisdom seems to be that to build a subproject as a static library so that it will link and run on all iOS architectures it is necessary to build an Aggregate target for the library, by running a build script which includes a lipo call to package the various binaries.

Is this still necessary in XCode 6?

Setting "Build Active Architecture Only" to NO sounds like it should do this without the need for a separate lipo script or an explicit Aggregate target.

Comment: I put most of my business logic in static libraries. I have never had to have a separate script to run lipo manually in order to build/use a static library going back to Xcode 4. I do use common xcconfig files in the static library and app project files.

Comment: Any hint whether there is still some circumstance in which this would be necessary, or is it just a holdover from Xcode 3? There are many recent blogs and stackoverflow posts recommending the lipo script, but my impression is it's not necessary. Configuring all the subprojects is certainly a pain and using common xconfig files is a valuable hint. Are there particular settings in the common xcconfig files that address this, other than "Build Active Architecture Only"? I assume the common xconfig file provides default settings which are overridden by settings in each project/subproject.

Comment: I dont know of any reason to ever need an extra script to run lipo (at least since Xcode4). As I said I have never needed to do it. I use the common xcconfig files so I can have one place to set all compiler settings for all projects in the workspace. I do usually have build active arch only set to YES for debug builds so development goes a little faster.